# Solving second-order linear difference equation with variable coefficients

Tags: recurrence-relations

Given the relation
$$
X_n = X_{n-1}g_{n-1} + X_{n+1}g_{n+1}
$$
where $g_{n}$ is some function of $n$, say $g_n = n$, is there a general method to find solutions for $X_n$? Thank you.

Comment: For general coefficients you won't find simple expressions. For specific cases you might be able to derive a formula.

Comment: @Lelouch Thanks. Are there any reference texts that I could take a look at to find out more?